# Extract an object's description through Beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, extract

I want to extract the description near the figure (the one that goes from "Figurine model" to "Stay Tuned :)") and store it into the variable `information` through BeautifulSoup. How can I do it? 
Here's my code, but I don't know how to continue it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get('https://www.myminifactory.com/object/3d-print-the-little-prince-4707')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
information =
```

I show you below the page from where I want to extract the object's description. Thank you in advance!
[image: The Page from where I want to extract the text]

Comment: Use `soup.select` with css selectors - you're almost there!

Comment: Something like `soup.find_all('div', class_='text-auto-link')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, not proud of the script because of the way I used the break statement. But the script works.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = r'https://www.myminifactory.com/object/3d-print-the-little-prince-4707'

html = urlopen(url).read()
Soup = BS(html,"lxml")
Desc = Soup.find('div',{'class':'short-text text-auto-link'}).text
description = ''
for line in Desc.split('\n'):
    if line.strip() == '_________________________________________________________________________':
        break
    if line.strip():
        description += line.strip()
print(description)
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the parent tag then looking for `<p>`, fliter the spaces and `____`

```
parent = soup.find("div",class_="row container-info-obj margin-t-10")
result = [" ".join(p.text.split()) for p in parent.find_all("p") if p.text.strip() and not "_"*8  in p.text]
#youtube_v = parent.find("iframe")["src"]
print(result)
```

Comment: It is not a "clean" output (I still get '\xa0' or other things like this inside the text).